# Missing Tweets from timeline

Tags: twitter

Basically, when I check my twitter timeline in the morning (say about 9am), it shows all the tweets from all who I follow but skips tweets before that (say tweets posted before 7am).

I'm pretty sure there's some problem because when for e.g. I check follower A's timeline, they posted tweets 2 hours ago but it didn't show on my timeline.

Sometimes during the day, my timeline becomes empty and shows only the last 10 tweets and hides all tweets made from since the morning.

Saw somewhere on another forum that un-checking "Tailor Twitter based on my recent website visits" on Twitter settings should solve it but it hasn't.

Any help?

Comment: It happens both on my phone (Nexus 4) and my Laptop (windows 7-Chrome). So I don't think the device I used it on has an issue.

Answer (score 1):

On a lighter note, are those persons whom you follow are in same timezones?

Anyways, this steps should fix this.

1. Login to twitter and navigate to the settings gear icon
2. Choose Settings.
3. Scroll down to the Personalization section.
4. Uncheck the Tailor Twitter based on my recent website visits selection.
5. Then save the changes!

This should fix this issue.

Comment: No. Some of them are 4-5 hours ahead of my timezone. I've said in my question that un-checking that option doesn't solve the problem :(